# Temproray Asp.net files error

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, temporary-files

Hi when building my application I am getting some temporary files shown in Solution Explorer under Miscellaneous Files lie App_Web_YDKG.VB with following code block in that generating error

```
Protected ReadOnly Property Profile() As System.Web.Profile.DefaultProfile
    Get
        Return CType(Me.Context.Profile,System.Web.Profile.DefaultProfile)
    End Get
End Property
```

Error :

> Error  58  'Protected ReadOnly Property Profile() As System.Web.Profile.DefaultProfile' has multiple definitions with identical signatures.    C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\infinityvb\2ae71c27\d560144b\App_Web_pwduczex.38.vb   456

Answer (score 2):

stop the Visual Studio and delete temporary files from the .NET framework folder. Usually it is here:

```
[Windows Folder]\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this yesterday - a reboot fixed it. I can't say for certain what caused it or the 'correct' solution.

Answer (score 0):

I keep a batch file in my environment path just for these circumstances... wrap this up in a .bat or .cmd file:

```
REM ClearTemp.cmd 

@echo off 
net stop w3svc

del "%WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\*.*" /s /f /q
for /d %%d in ("%WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\*") do rmdir "%%d" /s /q 

net start w3svc
pause
```

Comment: Hi all Thanks for your replys 
Hi Saul Dolgin its quite surprising that people know DOS at that much level
I have delete all temporary files but when i againg build the solution again its created there

Comment: @Ankur There must be more to this error. The temporary folder will always have files created in it upon running the web application. I suggest you hunt down all the definitions of this "Profile" property and make sure they are not colliding in your page class. Maybe you have multiple declarations of the same property which are somehow conflicting with each other upon compilation?  Is the property declared in a code-behind as well as the ASPX or designer class?